# Photoshop, can you remove a background simular to what Photobooth does?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

Is there an easy way in photoshop(cs 5.5) to remove backgrounds from a batch of photos that all have the same background? Kinda like green screen only with any background? In otherwords if I have a picture of the background by itself and then various objects in front that background, can I batch remove the real background. Photobooth in OSX does this when you have to step out of the shot for a few secounds and then when you step back in it can replace the background.

Comment: so you have the 2 pics with and without? a differences or exclusion  overlaying of layers would work.  if you dont have both pics, then you have to manually select.  I dont see the point, if you took 2, why not just take a 3rd :-) on a single color background.

Comment: I don't have access to such a background in real life (I'm not a photographer, I'm a web programmer) and If I did have one I'd still be asking the same question here. Also it's not just 2 photo's but a bunch of them. I'm really new on the photoshop end of things, the exclusion/differences overlay is what I would like to know how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked long ago...

But I hope my answer is helpful for other friends :)

For select specific color or remove color in a photo,We can use the magic wand tool.

[image]

After select ,the Using gradien tool or paint bucket tool for change the color.( delete or eraser tool for remove color)

[image]

And finally,We had a beautiful sun shining. ;)

[image]